# Reactjs, Generate JSX element from array using map

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, jsx

I am dealing with how to generate a JSX element inside return of a React component using map.
I am trying to make a dynamic form and the source is a given array:

I have two types of forms and the key "tipo" is the condition

Array with data:

```
let data = [
  { tipo: "input",
    label: "label1",
    name: "name1",
    placeholder: "placeholder1",
    defaultValue: "defaulvalue1",
  },
  { tipo: "datepiker",
    label: "label2",
    name: "name2",
    placeholder: "placeholder2",
    defaultValue: "defaulvalue2",
  },

];
```

The default normal code is: ( form type: input).

```
        <FormItem label="labe1">
          <Input name="name1" placeholder="placeholder1" defaultValue=defaultvalue1 />
        </FormItem>
```

In case we have a condition datepike we just replace with:

```
<DatePicker name="name"  defaultValue={moment("defaultvalue1")} />
```

Esto es un intento incompleto:

```
        <div>
          {data.map((value) => (
            <Fragment>
            <FormItem label={value.label}>

              *** condition *** if input or datepike

           </FormItem>
           </Fragment>


          ))}
        </div>
```

Any idea on how to acomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the `&&` condition on `tipo` and render accordingly.

```
<div>
  {data.map(({ label, tipo, name, defaultValue, placeholder }) => (
    <Fragment>
      <FormItem label={label}>
        {tipo === "input" && (
          <Input
            name={name}
            placeholder={placeholder}
            defaultValue={defaultvalue}
          />
        )}
        {tipo === "datepiker" && (
          <DatePicker name={name} defaultValue={moment(defaultValue)} />
        )}
      </FormItem>
    </Fragment>
  ))}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a tenary operation:

```
<div>
      {data.map((value) => (
        <Fragment>
        <FormItem label={value.label}>

          {value.tipo === "input" ? <Input name="name1" /> : <DatePicker name="name"/>}


       </FormItem>
       </Fragment>


      ))}
</div>
```